# gnuplot error - system evaluation not supported by MS-Windows 32 bit

Tags: gnuplot

On my vista desktop I find no error prompt. But on the xp side of my mac (intel) dual booting, both 4.44 and 4.43 gave the same error (warning: system evaluation not supported by MS-Windows 32 bit) while attempting plot command using external txt file as follows,

```
    G N U P L O T
    Version 4.4 patchlevel 4
    last modified November 2011
    System: MS-Windows 32 bit

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2011
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help seeking-assistance"
    immediate help:   type "help"
    plot window:      hit 'h'

Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot>  plot      "fpdfs3f1.txt" u 1:4 t `S1' w l lw 5
     warning: system evaluation not supported by MS-Windows 32 bit

gnuplot> plot      "fpdfs3f1.txt" u 1:4 t
                                      ^
     expecting "title" for plot

gnuplot>
```

Can anybody help me how can I resolve the problem? Many thanks for the helps in advance.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the quotation in title with "S1" solved the problem.